# Bash and Ubuntu Commands

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, rvm

I have a problem with bash currently. I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on a server I ssh into to do Rails development and something happened and now I am unable to use RVM as it is installed. The error I get is "bash: ZSH_VERSION: unbound variable" when I try to run the 'rvm' command. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try entering the command `zsh` before you enter whatever you enter to use RVM.

Comment: That works to let me use RVM again, thanks! Why is it doing that though? I gotta work out a conflict because apparently somebody reinstalled another version of Ruby outside of RVM on this as well...

Comment: The reason I thought saying `zsh` might help is that it looked like the "login shell" of your account on the Ubuntu box got switched from zsh to bash.  You can avoid the need to say `zsh` every time you ssh into the Ubuntu box by changing your login shell with the chpass command. Specifically, `chpass -s /bin/zsh`.   If that does not work, it is `chpass -s /usr/bin/zsh`.  Don't know about the other version of Ruby.

Comment: Try adding your explanation in the comment into the answer its self, it'll be easier for other people to spot in the future